# Mice imputation with a small number of missing values - test/train set may have no missing values

Tags: r, multiple-imputation, resampling, mice

When performing resampling, I wish to perform the same imputation on the test set as I performed on the training set, which is accepted practice. So, when imputing with MICE, I generate a predictor matrix when imputing the training set and use the same predictor matrix when imputing the test set.

This works fine if there are plenty of missing values. However the following situations can arise if the data set is small and/or has only a small number of missing values:

- training set has missing values but test set has no missing values
- training set has no missing values but the test set does have missing values
- both training and test sets have missing values

The first case is easy to handle - just return the original test set as it has no missing values.

In the second case, the mice predictor matrix created on the training set contains all zeroes and so cannot be used to impute the test set or it will cause an error - i.e. Error in edit.setup(data, setup, ...): `mice` detected constant and/or collinear variables. No predictors were left after their removal.\n" (In fact there are no collinear variables, but edit.setup checks for an all-zero predictor matrix and outputs this message as a result.) So a new predictor matrix has to be created for the test set. Is this valid?

In the final case, this works most of the time, but can cause problems if a particular column has missing values in only the training or test sets but not both.

Is there a better way to do this? Should I just regenerate the predictor matrix in the test set every time?